# How can I change forms dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 2 different models called `Parent` and `Child`.

I have a page called `House` that has the `link_to` to both forms on it:

**pages/house.html.erb**

`link_to "Parent", new_parent_path`

`link_to "Child", new_child_path`

When you start on the page it is empty with no forms.

I want to be able to click the `new_parent` link and generate the parent form on the same page but if I click the `new_child` link I want to remove the parent form and replace it with the child form by AJAX. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually very simple to create. [This question](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=44537) and [this one](http://notes.rehali.com/?p=97) helped me understand AJAX and jquery better.

Lets use the parent as an example:

I put the `format.js` in my controller for the `new` action:

```
ParentsController

def new
 @parent = Parent.new

 respond_to do |format|
  format.js
 end
end
```

I delete my `parents/new.html.erb` as a personal choice and replace it with `new.js.erb` that will be called by my `"Parent" link_to`.

```
# parents/new.js.erb

$("#generate-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'parents/form', locals: { parent: @parent })) %>");
```

Then create a Parent form in a partial that is `remote => true` for AJAX.

```
# parents/_form.html.erb

<%= form_for(@parent, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :full_name %>    
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Done' %>
<% end %>
```

Then I have one page that holds both forms.

```
PagesController

def index

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

Then the links on that page for both parent and child.

```
#pages/index.html.erb

<li><%= link_to "Parent", new_parent_path, :remote => true %></li>
<li><%= link_to "Child", new_child_path, :remote => true %></li>

<div id="generate-form">
</div>
```

The `remote => true` of my links and form will respond to the `js` format of my `new` action and my `div id="generate-form"` acts as the boss, placing either form partial inside of it. This automatically replaces one with the other depending on the link you click, thus resulting in changing forms dynamically.

Note: The code for the child model is the same (except for form fields). Just replace the Model name (Parent to Child).

Answer (score 4):

I think it will be easier to do it without Ajax, but with css. Generate the 2 forms in the page (using partials for example), and put than inside an hidden div (css style: `display: none`), and use javascript with your links to show/hide the div containing the form you want to display (with JQuery [show and hide effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/basics/))

Comment: But what happens if I have more models like `Car`, `Dog`, etc? Wouldn't that make the page take a longer time to load?

Comment: For forms to create new items, you won't hit the database, and page load time won't measurably increase. If you need forms to edit existing things, then you should still do this in CSS and use JSON to populate them.